# Why is my image not displaying ? cshtml

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to display an image and I don't understand where my error is. I checked questions on the topic, but without result.

I've got an image in a `byte[]` type object : `imageBuffer`. I'm sure the everything is ok till here, the following code is functioning.

```
unsafe
{
    fixed (byte* ptr = imageBuffer)
    {
        using (Bitmap image = new Bitmap(20 * lengthList, 20 * lengthList, 20 * lengthList * 4,
                   PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb, new IntPtr(ptr)))
        {
            image.Save(@"C:\Users\FS091843\Desktop\ Stations\Station1\greyscale.png");
        }          
    }
}
```

(PS : my `imageBuffer` object has before the Bitmap creation no dimensions (I mean, it is no 2D array) : it is more precisely a `byte[400 * lengthList * lengthList * 4]`)

As the `convertbase64()` can't figure out the dimensions without indications, I tried this :

```
// Some stuff before
DashboardPageModel dashboard = new DashboardPageModel();
unsafe
{
    fixed (byte* ptr = imageBuffer)
    {
        using (Bitmap image = new Bitmap(20 * lengthList, 20 * lengthList, 20 * lengthList * 4,
           PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb, new IntPtr(ptr)))
        {
            using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
            {
                image.Save(m, image.RawFormat);
                byte[] imageBytes = m.ToArray();
                image.Save(@"C:\Users\FS091843\Desktop\Stations\Station1\greyscale.png");

                dashboard.image = imageBytes;
                // Convert byte[] to Base64 String

            }

        }
    }
}
return View(MVC.Views.Common.Dashboard.DashboardIndex, dashboard);
```

Where `dashboard` comes from my Model class (my project is an MVC project).

My View file finally looks like :

```
@model Serene7.Common.DashboardPageModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Dashboard";
    ViewData["PageId"] = "Dashboard";
}

@section Head {
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/iCheck/flat/blue.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Scripts/morris/morris.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Scripts/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Scripts/datepicker/datepicker3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Scripts/daterangepicker/daterangepicker-bs3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Scripts/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.min.css">
<script src="~/Scripts/raphael/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/morris/morris.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/knob/jquery.knob.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/daterangepicker/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/adminlte/pages/dashboard.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/adminlte/demo.js"></script>
}

@section ContentHeader {
    <h1>@LocalText.Get("Navigation.Dashboard")<small>@Html.Raw(Texts.Site.Dashboard.ContentDescription)</small></h1>
}

<!-- Small boxes (Stat box) -->
<div class="row">...</div><!-- /.row -->
    <!-- Main row -->
<img src="data:image/png;base64,@(Convert.ToBase64String(Model.image))" alt="Red dot"/><!-- not really a red dot, had no idea what to enter as description -->
<div class="row">...</div>
```

and I get as a result : [image: fail]

Why isn't it functioning ?

Here is the html output

```
//<head>...</head>
<body id="s-LoginPage" class="no-navigation">
<script id="Template_Membership_LoginPanel" type="text/template">
<div class="flex-layout">
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <h3>Welcome to SERENE (Serenity Application Template)</h3>
    <form id="~_Form" action="">
        <div class="s-Form">
            <div class="fieldset ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
                <div id="~_PropertyGrid"></div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="buttons">
                <button id="~_LoginButton" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                    Sign In
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="actions">
                <a href="/Account/ForgotPassword"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>&nbsp;Forgot password?</a>
                <a href="/Account/SignUp"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>&nbsp;Register a new account</a>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</script>



<div class="page-content">
    <div id="LoginPanel">

    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function() {
    new Serene7.Membership.LoginPanel($('#LoginPanel')).init();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

[image]

The image looks like : [image]

Comment: Where should your image be in the screenshot?

Comment: The small "Red dot" thing under the blue box :)

Comment: Do you get any errors in your console? And can you show the rendered html for this image?

Comment: What does the rendered HTML output look like?

Comment: Just open the browser's dev tool to check the path, it can only be a 404....

Comment: @DoeJowns If you browse to the location where you save the image are you able to open and see it in windows image viewer or paint brush? Also if you are using `byte[]` format, try removing the Base64 hints in html image element.

Comment: @SivaGopal Yes, I get the image in windows image viewer. What does the "base64 hints" refers to ?

Comment: @SivaGopal This is an inline image. You need to prefix the base64 data with `data:mimetype;base64,`.

Comment: @TezWingfield This is an inline image; it cannot be 404.

Comment: I edited my post ! Here is the rendered html for this image (@Jerodev @Poke...)

Comment: @Jerodev I edited my post and found some "errors" : mainly, the load of symbols was skipped", or this error : `"iisexpress.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131484665986021319): "C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_de_b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.resources.dll" geladen. Das Modul wurde ohne Symbole erstellt.`

Comment: The relevant image is not in the HTML output you posted. So that won’t help at all. I want to know how the resulting `img src` looks like.

Comment: @poke my mistake, apologise.

Comment: Can you add just the rendered image tag?

Comment: @Jerodev this is quite long, i just put a screenshot of the beginning/end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// …
using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream()) 
{
    image.Save(m, image.RawFormat);
    byte[] imageBytes = m.ToArray();

    // …
```

You are storing *raw* bytes in the memory stream. It is just by chance that your image viewing tool displays the file properly because most image viewers are built to (mostly) ignore file extensions and try to render whatever is appropriate for them.

You need to actually convert your image into a PNG file in order to get the actual PNG bytes out of it:

```
// …
using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream()) 
{
    image.Save(m, ImageFormat.Png); // convert to PNG
    byte[] imageBytes = m.ToArray();

    // …
```

Once you did that, the bytes will be proper PNG data, so it should also render in the browser properly, and the file on your disk should become a lot smaller since it’s no longer raw bitmap data.

Comment: What does the rendered HTML output look like now? Can you please upload the stored image somewhere (ideally on some non-image file host that does *not* attempt to compress the image)?

Comment: I sent the html to hoodiezouz@yopmail.com :) http://www.yopmail.com/en/

Comment: Is that the HTML **after** changing the image format to PNG?

Comment: Yes ! I included the `image.Save(m, ImageFormat.Png);` line !

Comment: I included all your changes, but it still doesn't work ! Is it possible that my program hasn't taken it in consideration ?

Comment: Ok don't know why but I copied it in another program and your trick works now !

Comment: Good to hear that! :)